# Get Mac Adress of IPAD 2 with monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, macos, xamarin.ios

```
  foreach (var netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) 
  {

     if (netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211) 
      {
       var address = netInterface.GetPhysicalAddress();
       string c=  BitConverter.ToString(address.GetAddressBytes());

        }
 }
```

my i pad shows like 020000000 output, but my simulator shows correct, is there a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the MAC address is no longer possible in iOS7.

Apple removed this together with the ability to get a device unique ID.

You can find information for instance [here](http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/14/ios-7-eliminates-mac-address-as-tracking-option-signaling-final-push-towards-apples-own-ad-identifier-technology/).

There are alternatives like the vendor ID or the advertising ID. However, none of these 100% replaces the previous really unique IDs. See Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW49).

Comment: Read my answer: no, there is not. The closest you can get is the vendor ID which will be the same as there is at least one app from you (com.whatever.*) on the device.